# Is there a way in which a background video keeps playing when you navigate through a static website?

Tags: audio, video, background

this website is not using ajax to update sections of the site with content,  its a static site and therefore moves from one html page to the other in the classic way.

each page has a video element embedded which plays the same video.

clearly this means each time a user clicks to navigate to a different page, the video will restart.

what approaches can be taken to enable the video to maintain its position no matter which page the user visits ?

I understand each time a user clicks a hyperlink to navigate to a different page, a new http request is performed and there is the request and retrieval of this html page.

I'm curious whether I can achieve what I'm looking for without using AJAX.  be interested to hear from you all on this.

Comment: if you have to maintain the current structure then storing the currentTime for the video in a cookie and using that on each page refresh would be a clunky solution ... the only way to keep it seamless is move to a single page solution and use ajax to load and dynamically update the rest of the page content

Comment: i thought as much.  I ended up using jquery .load() method to load html from the server without page refresh.  I'm able to update just 'sections' of the web page without loading each new one entirely.  nice. :-)